# Simplify function code while maintaining readability

Tags: python, django, code-inspection

This code works, but seems too redundant to me.

Is it possible to somehow simplify it while maintaining functionality and readability?

```
has_videos = self.request.query_params.get('has_videos')
if has_videos:
    if has_videos == 'true':
        entries = User.objects.filter(videos__isnull=False)
    elif has_videos == 'false':
        entries = User.objects.filter(videos__isnull=True)
else:
    entries = User.objects.all()
```

I tried to write in one line using the ternary operator, but the readability disappeared completely

```
entries = Pet.objects.all() if has_photos not in ['true', 'false'] \
else Pet.objects.filter(photos__isnull=False) if has_photos == 'true' \
else Pet.objects.filter(photos__isnull=True)
```

Comment: `"false" is not None` returns `True` because that string is... not None. `if "false":` executes the code because the string `"false"` is not empty. Checking against None identity is not a way to check whether a string is empty. The empty string `""` is not None either yet it's empty and `if ""` never executes code.

Comment: For start, why the use of strings `true` and `false`?

Comment: @buran because it's query parameter in http request, i just parse it and filter in db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the *outer* if statement.

```
if has_videos == 'true':
    entries = User.objects.filter(videos__isnull=False)
elif has_videos == 'false':
    entries = User.objects.filter(videos__isnull=True)
else:
    entries = User.objects.all()
```

---

Less duplication, still readable(?).

```
d = {'true':False, 'false':True}
try:
    entries = User.objects.filter(videos__isnull=d[has_videos])
except KeyError:
    entries = User.objects.all()
```

Comment: Note: this is slightly different- and almost certainly for the better. In the OP's code it's possible for `entries` to not get assigned to at all if the `has_videos` value is set but does not equal `'true'` or `'false'`. In this refactor, `entries` will always be set, which is desirable.

Comment: it seems to me that this will slow down the program, because if `has videos` is None, then two unnecessary checks `if` will be made

Comment: @Анонимныйволшебник That's a micro optimization. The difference is likely microseconds. If you're in that tight a loop in a webserver, python is not going to be the right language choice anyways.

Comment: I was going to suggest a version of your second block and I like that stagey,  just note that this is not exactly the same result as the original code that would do nothing in the event that `has_videos` was say "unknown", though I'm guessing it is ultimately what the OP actually wants